# Call Children's functions from parent

Tags: java, function, parent, children

I'm very new at Java, been coding C++ for a while and OOP and an exciting new adventure for me.

I've tried to search on the issue, but I haven't been able to transfer the answers into my personal problem, so here goes:

**Loop.java**

```
public class Loop {
public int x;
public int y;
public int size;

public static void main(String [] args){
    new Loop(4, 4 ,2 );
}
private boolean game;

//---------------------------------------- constructor
public Loop(){
    }
public Loop(int height, int width, int cell_size){
    x = width;
    y = height;
    size = cell_size;
    System.out.println("Loop()");
    game = true;
    new Build_Cells(y,x);
    //run();
}
};
```

**Build_Cells.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Build_Cells extends Loop {
private List<List<Cell>> map = new ArrayList<List<Cell>>();
public int col;
public int rows;
public void printMap(){
    System.out.println("PrintMap()");
    for( int i = 0; i < map.size() /** col */; i++){
        for( int u = 0; u < map.get(i).size() /** rows */ ;u++){
            System.out.print(map.get(i).get(u).getState());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public Cell getCell(int a, int b){
    return map.get(a).get(b);
}
//---------------------------------------- constructor
public Build_Cells(){
}
public Build_Cells( int by, int bx){
    System.out.println("Build_Cells()");
    col = by;
    rows = bx;
    for( int i = 0; i < col ; i++){
        List<Cell> colObj = new ArrayList<Cell>(rows);
        map.add(y, colObj);
        for(int u = 0; u < rows; u++){
            colObj.add( new Cell() );
        }
    }
    printMap();
}
};
```

**Cell.java**

```
public class Cell extends Build_Cells {
private int state;
private int nemesis;
private int next;
private int getNem(int cs){
    int cata;
    if(cs == 1)
        cata = 0;
    else if(cs == (0 | 2 | 3) )
        cata = 1;
    else
        cata = 6;
    return cata;
}


//---------------------------------------- constructor
public Cell(){
    System.out.println("Cell()");
    set_state(5);
}
public void set_state(int input){
    state = input;
    nemesis = getNem(state);
}
public int getState(){
    return state;
}
};
```

How do I make `Build_Cells`'s `getCell()` function and `Cell`'s `getState()` and `setState()` functions available for `Loop` to use?

Comment: You likely need to rethink your class heirarchy

Comment: Where exactly do you want to call these? Because you instantiate BuildCells. After instantiation you can invoke its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You've created instance of `Build_Cell` without storing a reference to it. If you change:

```
new Build_Cells(y,x);
```

to

```
Build_Cells buildCells = new Build_Cells(y,x);
```

you'll be able to call `buildCells.getCell()` from `Loop`. You can get the cell's state by calling `buildCells.getCell().getState()` or set its state by calling `buildCells.getCell().setState()`.

Also, `Cell` probably shouldn't be extending `Build_Cells` because it doesn't use any functionality from it. You can read more about OOP in Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).